# How to ignore generating tsconfig.json in Next.js

Tags: typescript, npm, next.js

My next.js folder structure looks like:

```
site
│  package.json
│  tsconfig.json
│  tslint.json
│  yarn.lock
│
├─dist
│      index.js
│
└─src
       index.ts
```

The problem is that every `next build src` generates new `tsconfig.json` in `src` folder. I already configured TS in `tsconfig.json` placed in parent directory so I don't need new configuration file.

Is there a way how to ignore generating `tsconfig.json` file during next.js build?

- next.js - 10.0.5
- typescript- 3.8.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script should run `next build` instead.

Next.js automatically detects the `src/` folder when it's there.